# Customise Restrictions passcode on iphone

Tags: password

I know you can customise the iPhone main passcode to strengthen the security but there doesn't seem to be that option when doing the same when setting up restrictions. After I have written it down somewhere I don't want to remember the passcode, and I definitely will if't it only 4 numbers. 
Is it possible to write an app for something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Very much doubt Apple would allow any app to access that API.
The restrictions passcode is so hard you need to wipe the phone & start over if you forget it.

If you really don't want to know what the code is, get someone else to set one & not tell you what it is. You then have the opportunity of changing your mind later, assuming *they* remember it.